# How can I successfully post data in PHP? Undefined variable: name_result in check.php

Tags: php, html

I'm now making a contact form, but I get the error below.
Undefined variable: name_result in check.php

I want to make the website like:
Welcome Mr.(Ms.) name

HTML(Updated)↓

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contact form</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="check.php">
        <div>
        <div>
        <label for="" class="font">Title:</label>
        <label for="" class="font">Name:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr.">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Ms.">
　　　　　　　<input type="text" name="name" value="" class="text"><br>
            </div>
            <br>
        <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

check.php(Updated)↓

```
<?php
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];  
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $name_result = '';
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
                if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
                    $name_result = 'welcome ' . $gender . $name;
                }else{
                    $name_result = 'Oops! No name typed';
                }
            }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>confirm</h1>
    <div>
    <p><?php echo $name_result; ?></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are various times when you use values before checking if they are set - `$gender = $_POST['gender']` is done before `if(isset($_POST['gender']))` etc.

Comment: Try add `name='submit' ` in input submit.

Comment: can you add your updated code in the question so that we can check the issue

Comment: I have updated my changes.

Comment: Plz marked the answer as correct whose answer you think is correct @Sanae

Comment: I marked it! Thank you also for telling me how to use this web :) @Amanjot Kaur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In check.php, you should declare $name_result as an empty string. and for accessing the post variables or get data, they should have a name attribute. So, give the submit button a particular name like submit as you are using.

Also, you have a syntax error at

> `$name_result = 'welcome ' . $gender . $name];`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contact form</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="check.php">
            <div>
            <div>
            <label for="" class="font">Title:</label>
            <label for="" class="font">Name:</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr.">Mr.
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Ms.">Ms.
    　　　　　　　<input type="text" name="name" value="" class="text"><br>
                </div>
                <br>
            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Check.php

```
<?php
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];  
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $name_result='';
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
                if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
                    $name_result = 'welcome ' . $gender .' '. $name;
                }else{
                    $name_result = 'Oops! No name typed';
                }
            }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>confirm</h1>
    <div>
    <p><?php echo $name_result; ?></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

declare name_result variable globally at the top of the php script with blank string.

```
$name_result = '';
```

for now it is functioning as the local variable with limited scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry but my understanding is very little about PHP as I'm new to this industry. I tried as you mentioned, but I just got blank result in the name content. How could I display "Welcome [Mr./Ms] [name]" ?

Comment: in this case, value for the radio button will Mr./Ms respectively instead of male & female.
value attribute will pass as the post parameter

Comment: update radio button as 
**
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mr.">Mr.
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Ms.">Ms.
**
and print it as follows 
**
$name_result = 'welcome ' . $gender . ' ' .  $name;
**

Comment: just realized, you have not set any "name" attribute to your submit button.
assign name attribute to submit button as well, as you are checking the condition of its value in check.php file.
also, use htmlspecialchars() instead of h() to print to result with echo. 

** <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> **

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. Yes, there were some other people pointed out about that, and I modified that point, but it's still the same. I don't know why..:(

Comment: have you tried to update the submit button code as above?

** <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> **

just add name attribute with as above and you will get result for sure.

Comment: Yes, I added the name attribute.

Comment: Also, replace **<?php echo h($name_result); ?>** with **<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name_result); ?>**

Answer (score 1):

**give name to your submit button name="submit"**

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

**define $name_result as global variable**

```
<?php
     $gender = $_POST['gender'];  
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $name_result="";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
             if(isset($_POST['gender'])){
               $name_result = 'welcome ' . $gender . $name];
               }else{
                    $name_result = 'Oops! No name typed';
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried the code above, but the result was blank in the line of name: ...

Comment: where you echo $name_result remove h and brackets from their

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. Unfortunately, it's still blank..:( I'm trying other ways, but it doesn't work.